# Import module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a object created in `src/some/file.js`

```
 module.exports = export_obj
```

Now i want to access this object from another file src/other/file2.js
I tried doing `require('export_obj')` but it gives error:Error: Cannot find module

Comment: Use require('./export_obj')

Answer (score 1):

The variable name you use inside the module before you copy its value to `exports` is irrelevant (and impossible to determine before the file is loaded anyway).

You need to use the **filename** in the `require` statement.

```
require('../other/file2.js')
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to require with relative path.

```
other = require('../other/file2');
```

Without relative path, nodeJS will try to find the package inside node_modules (locally and globally).